# How can I use OrderingFilter without exposing the names of the fields in the database

Tags: django, django-views, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a model that uses the `OrderingFilter` Backend. Right now only ordering by field `id` is allowed.

I want to give the option for ordering by other fields too but without having to expose the field names in my database. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I created an AliasedOrderingFilter that should fit this need rather well. It extends the ordering_fields attribute to allow tuples for fields as well as strings.  For example you could set the views ordering_fields to:

```
ordering_fields = (('alias1', 'field1'),('alias2', 'field2'), 'field3')
```

Using this class in a request with `ordering=alias1,-alias2,field3` will result in:

```
qs.order_by('field1', '-field2', 'field3)
```

The class:

```
class AliasedOrderingFilter(OrderingFilter):
    ''' this allows us to "alias" fields on our model to ensure consistency at the API level
        We do so by allowing the ordering_fields attribute to accept a list of tuples.
        You can mix and match, i.e.:
        ordering_fields = (('alias1', 'field1'), 'field2', ('alias2', 'field2')) '''

    def remove_invalid_fields(self, queryset, fields, view):      
        valid_fields = getattr(view, 'ordering_fields', self.ordering_fields)
        if valid_fields is None or valid_fields == '__all__':
            return super(AliasedOrderingFilter, self).remove_invalid_fields(queryset, fields, view)

        aliased_fields = {}
        for field in valid_fields:
            if isinstance(field, basestring):
                aliased_fields[field] = field
            else:
                aliased_fields[field[0]] = field[1]

        ordering = []
        for raw_field in fields:
            invert = raw_field[0] == '-'
            field = raw_field.lstrip('-')
            if field in aliased_fields:
                if invert:
                    ordering.append('-{}'.format(aliased_fields[field]))
                else:
                    ordering.append(aliased_fields[field])
        return ordering
```

Comment: Thanks, that works. In the function definition I had to say `filters.OrderingFilter`. And in the `ViewSet`, add `AliasedOrderingFilter` in `filter_backends`.

Comment: need to add `request` arg to `remove_invalid_fields` declaration

Answer (score 18):

```
pip install django-filter
```

In your view:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets, filters
from django_filters.filters import OrderingFilter
from .models import MyList
from .serializers import MyListSerializer

class MyFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    surname = django_filters.CharFilter(name="model_field_name_2")

    order_by_field = 'ordering'
    ordering = OrderingFilter(
        # fields(('model field name', 'parameter name'),)
        fields=(
            ('model_field_name_1', 'name'),
            ('model_field_name_2', 'surname'),
            ('model_field_name_3', 'email'),
        )
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyList
        fields = ['model_field_name_2',]

class MyListViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = MyListSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_class = MyFilter
    
    def get_queryset(self):
        return MyList.objects.all()
```

And you could do something like this:

```
/my-list?ordering=name,surname,email
/my-list?ordering=-email&surname=taylor
```

django-filter docs:
https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ref/filters.html#orderingfilter

drf docs:
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend

Comment: In `django-filter==2.0`, `filter_class` has been renamed to [`filterset_class`](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/guide/migration.html?).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do that by using the `ordering_fields` attribute in your view like:

```
class YourViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = yourSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter,)
    ordering_fields = ('field1', 'field2')
```

In `ordering_fields` you mention all the fields by which you want to allow ordering.

Here `field1` and `field2` need not be present in the serializer `fields` attribute and therefore they won't be in your API response.

Update:
Your request url should be like:

```
http://example.com/api/users?ordering=field1
```

`ordering` is the query parameter. You need to set `ordering`  with the field name with which you want to order your queryset.

you can learn more [here](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#orderingfilter)

Comment: I don't get it. In that case with what argument will the request ask to order by field `field1` for example?

Comment: I already know that. What I am asking is, is there a way to use an alias for the field name instead on the field name? Namely, can I have a request that would look like this 
`api/users?ordering=alias_for_field1`? So that I don't have to expose the internal naming of the fields.

Comment: @PGryllos In this case I would recommend you to override the `get_queryset` method and handle the ordering manually instead of using `OrderingFilter` Backend. If you insist on `OrderingFilter` Backend then you may have to create a new custom filter class which inherits `OrderingFilter` class and override the `OrderingFilter` methods to your requirement.

Comment: This is not the answer to the question. Question is about substituting parameter  names with model names.